# Sync data with GUID

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-datastore

I need to sync between the third part DB(primary key is GUID) and Google Datastore.
I get the updated record list from the third part DB.
What is the best way to sync between two?
I know one way like below, but it looks not efficient at all.

1. Get the updated list from third part DB.  It only has GUID.
2. Find the key from Google Datastore with GUID
3. Update Google Datastore with the Key.

The above scenario causes two Google Datastore transactions: One is to find the key by GUID, then Update the record on Google Datatore by key.

Is there any better way than this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If the `GUID` is the primary key of the datastore, the datastore `KEY` can be generated without querying datastore and you can just use `update`. If not, the method you provided is the only way.